# How to get itemID or UniqueID after Add-PnPFile or Find-PnPFile?

Tags: pnp-powershell

I uploaded a file to SP library with 
    $f = Add-PnPFile  -Path "C:\temp\01.pdf" -Folder "documents"

What is best way to get the id or UniqueID of this new file?
I need this info to use Set-PnPListItem command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you need `Set-PnPListItem` after adding the file.

To add the properties of the file, you can just use the `Values` parameter and set them as below:

```
$f = Add-PnPFile -Path "C:\temp\01.pdf" -Folder "Documents" -Values
@{Title="01 Title";Description="Test description"}
```

Reference-  [Add-PnPFile](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/Add-PnPFile.md)

However, if you do need to use `Set-PnPListItem` directly after uploading the file, you can use it as below. We will first upload the file, then fetch it using the latest item id and then update it.

```
$f = Add-PnPFile -Path "C:\temp\01.pdf.pdf" -Folder "Documents"
$listItems = Get-PnPListItem -List "Documents"
$maxItemId = ($listItems.Id | measure-object -maximum).maximum;
Set-PnPListItem -List "Documents" -Identity $maxItemId -Values @{Title="01 Title";Description="Test description"}
```

or using `Get-PnPFile` to get list item and then update as below:

```
$f = Add-PnPFile -Path "C:\temp\01.pdf" -Folder "Documents"
$listItem = Get-PnPFile -Url "/sites/test/Documents/01.pdf" -AsListItem
$res = Set-PnPListItem -List "Documents" -Identity $listItem -Values @{Title="01 Title";Description="Test description"}
```

Comment: what is the output returns by Add-PnpFile i.e what is in $f object?

Comment: Using the maximum id as shown could result in a false match. For example, if a file was added in the time between add-pnpfile and the time Get-PnPListItem takes to return.

Comment: thx!  the -AsListItem is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = Add-PnPFile -Path "C:\temp\01.pdf" -Folder "Documents";
$listItem = Get-PnPFile -Url $file.ServerRelativeUrl -AsListItem;
Set-PnPListItem -List "Documents" -Identity $listItem["ID"] -Values @{Title="01 Title";Description="Test description"}
```